# overwrite save django method

Tags: python-3.x, django

I need to override Django's method save so when the purchase is made by a certain cpf, it is saved with "Approved" status. Can someone help me?

Follow the models.py

```
class Purchases(TimeStampedModel):
    APROVADO = "AP"
    EM_VALIDACAO = "VA"
    STATUS_CHOICHES = (
        (APROVADO, "Aprovado"),
        (EM_VALIDACAO, "Em validação"),
    )
    values = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)
    cpf = BRCPFField("CPF")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICHES, default=EM_VALIDACAO)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a new method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #your business logic

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: My logic is wrong, and I don't understand why

follow code:

`     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.cpf == 15350946056:
            self.status = "AP"
            super(Purchases, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Do you get errors or what it is stored in the db?

Comment: He is not saving.
when I post, it doesn't save

Comment: Could you also post the viewset and the serializer?

Comment: I managed to solve.
I'm using BRCPFField to get cpf, and it treats like chafield. So just make the cpf a string that works.
Thus:

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if self.cpf == "15350946056":
             self.status = "AP"
             super(Purchases, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
         else:
             self.status = "VA"
             super(Purchases, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.cpf == "15350946056":
        self.status = "AP"
        super(Purchases, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        self.status = "VA"
        super(Purchases, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The CPF is between " " because the BRCPFField deals with charfild, we need to transform the cpf into a string so that there is a comparison